# NPE in using scala Array.fill

Tags: scala

I am reading **Programming in Scala, Third Edition** (Also present in Fourth Edition), *by Lex Spoon; Bill Venners; Martin Odersky*, and trying out examples along the way.

Following example form the book | [Run in ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/xpTkkLR/0)

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]
  val height = contents.length
  val width = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}

class UniformElement(
  ch: Char,
  override val width: Int,
  override val height: Int
) extends Element {
  private val line = ch.toString * width
  def contents = Array.fill(height)(line)
}

val e: Element = new UniformElement('x', 2, 3)
```

gives **java.lang.NullPointerException**, when tried in REPL, or in Eclipse worksheet.

If I change

```
  private val line = ch.toString * width
```

to

```
  private def line = ch.toString * width
```

no error occurs.

Can someone explain, please?

I am using scala 2.11.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `contents` is still not defined in the constructor, when you define `line`. If line is a `val`, it does not pick the overridden `width`, instead it uses the abstract one which in turn uses `contents`, which is still undefined and you get the NPE. You can see this by looking at the stacktrace and noting that the NPE is thrown by the definition of `width` in the abstract class.

When `line` is defined as a method, it does not execute until you call it and by that time contents will be fully defined, because it can call `line` (another method) which will be fully defined.

[Run on ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/LoF9UBh/0)

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]
  val height = contents.length
  val width = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}

class UniformElement(
                      ch: Char,
                      override val width: Int,
                      override val height: Int
                    ) extends Element {
  private def line: String = ch.toString * width
  def contents = Array.fill(height)(line)
}

val e3: Element = new UniformElement('x', 2, 3)
```

Bottom line: you have a kind of "*circular dependency*" between `line` and `contents`.

Comment: kind of makes sense.
I removed the overrides from constructor params, and added those in class body. And that works without error. (appended question with updated class definition).
I guess, this is the correct way?

Thanks much!